# How do I set timeouts with the Sybase module in Python?

Tags: python, sybase

Occasionally I run into a problem where a query to sybase takes a very long time. I would like to wait 30 seconds or so, then timeout. Here is my code:

```
import Sybase

db = Sybase.connect('server','name','pass','database')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("select statement that takes a long time")
list1 = c.fetchall()

print list1
```

How do I rewrite my code so that when a query takes more than 30 seconds, it produces a empty list1?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no there's not. I would try asking on the python-sybase mailing list by emailing python-sybase-misc@lists.sourceforge.net, but I see [a previous question](http://sourceforge.net/p/python-sybase/mailman/message/28652480/) on there asking the same thing (nearly) with no response. I don't see any documentation that would indicate a `timeout` parameter to any method.

Answer (score 1):

I see two posibilitiues:

1. (Harder) Configure resource limit on server side. Here are details [1](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31644.1570/html/sag2/sag224.htm), [2](http://www.sypron.nl/quiz2009a.html).
2. (Easier) Run your Python code in separate thread and kill it after hit 30s limit. Here yuo have an [example](https://web.archive.org/web/20130503082442/http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-May/281943.html)

In your case for 2 option:

```
def func():
   db = Sybase.connect('server','name','pass','database')
   c = db.cursor()
   c.execute("select statement that takes a long time")
   list1 = c.fetchall()
   print list1

A = KThread(target=func)
A.start()
time.sleep(30)
if not A.isAlive():
   A.kill()
```

GL!